# RxJava2 - Chaining observables that emit different types

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm learning RxJava2 and I need to chain three observables:

The first one performs operations on the data:

```
Completable performOperations(Data data); // performs expensive operations.
```

The second one uploads data to a server1 and emits percentage progress.

```
Observable<Integer> uploadToServer1(Data data); // while it performs the upload, it calls several times onNext(progress) and finally calls onComplete().
```

The third one just informs to a server2 that the upload was done.

```
Completable informUploadedToServer2(Data data); // just calls a REST API.
```

I would like to show the progress in my Activity of the second observable and finally show success when the third one finishes successfully. If any of the three observables throws an exception I should show the error in the Activity as well.

I've tried to use `concat` to chain but it won't compile because `uploadToServer1` emits the Integer type and the rest doesn't.

```
public void upload(Data data, MyCallback callback) {
    Observable.concat(performOperations(data).toObservable(), uploadToServer1(data), informUploadedToServer2(data))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                        callback.onProgressChanged(integer);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        callback.onError();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        callback.onSuccess();
                    }
                });
}
```

I've seen that if I change to

```
Observable.concat(performOperations(data).<Integer>toObservable(), uploadToServer1(data), informUploadedToServer2(data).<Integer>toObservable())
```

it will work, however, is this the recommended approach?

What is more, what if the first observable emits non-Integers?, for example, a `DataDiff` object which would describe the modification after a certain operation was performed:

```
Observable<DataDiff> performOperations(Data data);
```

How should I subscribe so that I can listen for `onNext(Integer)` and also `onNext(DataDiff)` so that the Activity can update the view accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would do that in a different way, a more "streamy" approach.

First `performOperations()`, then use `andThen` operator to concatenate with the `Observable<Integer>`, and then you can use `concatWith` so that after that all the elements from the `Observable<Integer>` are emitted `informUploadedToServer2` is executed. You can then handle the `Integer` emitted in the subscription consumer, if you `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread)` you can than safely notify your `Activity` there

```
performOperations(data)
        .andThen(uploadToServer1(data))
        .concatWith(informUploadedToServer2(data))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Integer integer) throws Exception {
               // notify your Activity here
            }
        });
```

In case you needed to intercept the completion of one of the streams, you could use `doOnComplete`, for instance

```
performOperations(data)
        .doOnComplete(new Action() {
            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
               // after performOperations has completed but before 
               // uploadToServer1 has started
            }
        })
        .andThen(uploadToServer1(data))
        // ...
```

In case `performOperations()` returned an `Observable<DataDiff>`, you could use `doOnNext` to intercept all the events, and then use `ignoreElements` operator to convert it to a `Completable` and then use `andThen` as before

```
performOperations()
        .doOnNext(new Consumer<DataDiff>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(DataDiff dataDiff) throws Exception {
                // handle DataDiff here
            }
        })
        .ignoreElements()
        .andThen(uploadToServer1())
        // ...
```

Comment: Note that `concatWith(Completable)` was added in RxJava 2.1.10.